# Remove cell from Apple DateCell template

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, uitableview

Here is my latest Screenshot from the app:

[image: Screenshot]

Now I want to remove the cell 'Title' and the two cells '(other item 1)' and '(other item 2)'. How can I do that correctly? I'm keep getting Errors.

Here's **MyTableViewController.m** (edited by me and downloaded before from [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/samplecode/datecell/listings/MyTableViewController_m.html))

```
#import "MyTableViewController.h"

#define kPickerAnimationDuration    0.40   // duration for the animation to slide the date picker into view
#define kDatePickerTag              99     // view tag identifiying the date picker view

#define kTitleKey       @"title"   // key for obtaining the data source item's title
#define kDateKey        @"date"    // key for obtaining the data source item's date value

// keep track of which rows have date cells
#define kDateStartRow   1
#define kDateEndRow     2

static NSString *kDateCellID = @"dateCell";     // the cells with the start or end date
static NSString *kDatePickerID = @"datePicker"; // the cell containing the date picker
static NSString *kOtherCell = @"otherCell";     // the remaining cells at the end

#pragma mark -

@interface MyTableViewController ()

@property (nonatomic, strong) NSArray *dataArray;
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter;

// keep track which indexPath points to the cell with UIDatePicker
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSIndexPath *datePickerIndexPath;

@property (assign) NSInteger pickerCellRowHeight;


@property (nonatomic, strong) IBOutlet UIDatePicker *pickerView;

// this button appears only when the date picker is shown (iOS 6.1.x or earlier)
@property (nonatomic, strong) IBOutlet UIBarButtonItem *doneButton;

@end

#pragma mark -

@implementation MyTableViewController

/*! Primary view has been loaded for this view controller
 */
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    // setup our data source
    NSMutableDictionary *itemOne = [@{ kTitleKey : @"Title" } mutableCopy];
    NSMutableDictionary *itemTwo = [@{ kTitleKey : @"Startdatum",
                                       kDateKey : [NSDate date] } mutableCopy];
    NSMutableDictionary *itemThree = [@{ kTitleKey : @"Enddatum",
                                        kDateKey : [NSDate date] } mutableCopy];
    NSMutableDictionary *itemFour = [@{ kTitleKey : @"(other item1)" } mutableCopy];
    NSMutableDictionary *itemFive = [@{ kTitleKey : @"(other item2)" } mutableCopy];
    self.dataArray = @[itemOne, itemTwo, itemThree, itemFour, itemFive];

    self.dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
    [self.dateFormatter setDateStyle:NSDateFormatterShortStyle];    // show short-style date format
    [self.dateFormatter setTimeStyle:NSDateFormatterShortStyle];

    // obtain the picker view cell's height, works because the cell was pre-defined in our storyboard
    UITableViewCell *pickerViewCellToCheck = [self.tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:kDatePickerID];
    self.pickerCellRowHeight = pickerViewCellToCheck.frame.size.height;





    // if the local changes while in the background, we need to be notified so we can update the date
    // format in the table view cells
    //
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
                                             selector:@selector(localeChanged:)
                                                 name:NSCurrentLocaleDidChangeNotification
                                               object:nil];
}

- (void)dealloc
{
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] removeObserver:self
                                                    name:NSCurrentLocaleDidChangeNotification
                                                  object:nil];
}


#pragma mark - Locale

/*! Responds to region format or locale changes.
 */
- (void)localeChanged:(NSNotification *)notif
{
    // the user changed the locale (region format) in Settings, so we are notified here to
    // update the date format in the table view cells
    //
    [self.tableView reloadData];
}


#pragma mark - Utilities

/*! Returns the major version of iOS, (i.e. for iOS 6.1.3 it returns 6)
 */
NSUInteger DeviceSystemMajorVersion()
{
    static NSUInteger _deviceSystemMajorVersion = -1;
    static dispatch_once_t onceToken;
    dispatch_once(&onceToken, ^{

        _deviceSystemMajorVersion = [[[[[UIDevice currentDevice] systemVersion] componentsSeparatedByString:@"."] objectAtIndex:0] intValue];
    });

    return _deviceSystemMajorVersion;
}

#define EMBEDDED_DATE_PICKER (DeviceSystemMajorVersion() >= 7)

/*! Determines if the given indexPath has a cell below it with a UIDatePicker.

 @param indexPath The indexPath to check if its cell has a UIDatePicker below it.
 */
- (BOOL)hasPickerForIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    BOOL hasDatePicker = NO;

    NSInteger targetedRow = indexPath.row;
    targetedRow++;

    UITableViewCell *checkDatePickerCell =
        [self.tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:[NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:targetedRow inSection:2]];
    UIDatePicker *checkDatePicker = (UIDatePicker *)[checkDatePickerCell viewWithTag:kDatePickerTag];

    hasDatePicker = (checkDatePicker != nil);
    return hasDatePicker;
}

/*! Updates the UIDatePicker's value to match with the date of the cell above it.
 */
- (void)updateDatePicker
{
    if (self.datePickerIndexPath != nil)
    {
        UITableViewCell *associatedDatePickerCell = [self.tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:self.datePickerIndexPath];

        UIDatePicker *targetedDatePicker = (UIDatePicker *)[associatedDatePickerCell viewWithTag:kDatePickerTag];
        if (targetedDatePicker != nil)
        {
            // we found a UIDatePicker in this cell, so update it's date value
            //
            NSDictionary *itemData = self.dataArray[self.datePickerIndexPath.row - 1];
            [targetedDatePicker setDate:[itemData valueForKey:kDateKey] animated:NO];
        }
    }
}

/*! Determines if the UITableViewController has a UIDatePicker in any of its cells.
 */
- (BOOL)hasInlineDatePicker
{
    return (self.datePickerIndexPath != nil);
}

/*! Determines if the given indexPath points to a cell that contains the UIDatePicker.

 @param indexPath The indexPath to check if it represents a cell with the UIDatePicker.
 */
- (BOOL)indexPathHasPicker:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    return ([self hasInlineDatePicker] && self.datePickerIndexPath.row == indexPath.row);
}

/*! Determines if the given indexPath points to a cell that contains the start/end dates.

    @param indexPath The indexPath to check if it represents start/end date cell.
*/
- (BOOL)indexPathHasDate:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    BOOL hasDate = NO;

    if ((indexPath.row == kDateStartRow) ||
        (indexPath.row == kDateEndRow || ([self hasInlineDatePicker] && (indexPath.row == kDateEndRow + 1))))
    {
        hasDate = YES;
    }

    return hasDate;
}


#pragma mark - UITableViewDataSource


-(NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
{
    return 3;
}
- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    return ([self indexPathHasPicker:indexPath] ? self.pickerCellRowHeight : self.tableView.rowHeight);
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    if (section == 2) {
    if ([self hasInlineDatePicker])
    {
        // we have a date picker, so allow for it in the number of rows in this section
        NSInteger numRows = self.dataArray.count;
        return ++numRows;
    }

    return self.dataArray.count;
    } else {
        if (section == 0) {
            return 2;
        } else {
            return 1;
        }


    }
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{

    UITableViewCell *cell = nil;
    if (indexPath.section <= 1) {
        static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";


        // Configure the cell...
        //UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
        cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
        if (!cell) {
            cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
        }

        if (indexPath.section == 0) {
            switch (indexPath.row) {
                case 0:
                    cell.textLabel.text = @"Hausaufgaben";
                    cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryCheckmark;
                    break;
                case 1:
                    cell.textLabel.text = @"Prüfung";
                    break;

                default:
                    break;
            }

        } else {
            UITextField *lblMainLabel = [[UITextField alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(50, 9, 150, 25)];
            lblMainLabel.tag = 42;
            lblMainLabel.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"Helvetica-Neue" size:15];
            lblMainLabel.textColor = [UIColor blackColor];
            lblMainLabel.placeholder = @"Beschreibung";
            [cell.contentView addSubview:lblMainLabel];
                cell.textLabel.text = @"Mat";
            cell.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone;

        }
    } else {
    NSString *cellID = kOtherCell;

    if ([self indexPathHasPicker:indexPath])
    {
        // the indexPath is the one containing the inline date picker
        cellID = kDatePickerID;     // the current/opened date picker cell
    }
    else if ([self indexPathHasDate:indexPath])
    {
        // the indexPath is one that contains the date information
        cellID = kDateCellID;       // the start/end date cells
    }

    cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:cellID];

    if (indexPath.row == 0)
    {
        // we decide here that first cell in the table is not selectable (it's just an indicator)
        cell.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone;
    }

    // if we have a date picker open whose cell is above the cell we want to update,
    // then we have one more cell than the model allows
    //
    NSInteger modelRow = indexPath.row;
    if (self.datePickerIndexPath != nil && self.datePickerIndexPath.row < indexPath.row)
    {
        modelRow--;
    }

    NSDictionary *itemData = self.dataArray[modelRow];

    // proceed to configure our cell
    if ([cellID isEqualToString:kDateCellID])
    {
        // we have either start or end date cells, populate their date field
        //
        cell.textLabel.text = [itemData valueForKey:kTitleKey];
        cell.detailTextLabel.text = [self.dateFormatter stringFromDate:[itemData valueForKey:kDateKey]];
    }
   else if ([cellID isEqualToString:kOtherCell])
    {
        // this cell is a non-date cell, just assign it's text label
        //
        cell.textLabel.text = [itemData valueForKey:kTitleKey];
    }
    }

    return cell;
}

/*! Adds or removes a UIDatePicker cell below the given indexPath.

 @param indexPath The indexPath to reveal the UIDatePicker.
 */
- (void)toggleDatePickerForSelectedIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    [self.tableView beginUpdates];

    NSArray *indexPaths = @[[NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:indexPath.row + 1 inSection:2]];

    // check if 'indexPath' has an attached date picker below it
    if ([self hasPickerForIndexPath:indexPath])
    {
        // found a picker below it, so remove it
        [self.tableView deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:indexPaths
                              withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
    }
    else
    {
        // didn't find a picker below it, so we should insert it
        [self.tableView insertRowsAtIndexPaths:indexPaths
                              withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
    }

    [self.tableView endUpdates];
}

/*! Reveals the date picker inline for the given indexPath, called by "didSelectRowAtIndexPath".

 @param indexPath The indexPath to reveal the UIDatePicker.
 */
- (void)displayInlineDatePickerForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    // display the date picker inline with the table content
    [self.tableView beginUpdates];

    BOOL before = NO;   // indicates if the date picker is below "indexPath", help us determine which row to reveal
    if ([self hasInlineDatePicker])
    {
        before = self.datePickerIndexPath.row < indexPath.row;
    }

    BOOL sameCellClicked = (self.datePickerIndexPath.row - 1 == indexPath.row);

    // remove any date picker cell if it exists
    if ([self hasInlineDatePicker])
    {
        [self.tableView deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:@[[NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:self.datePickerIndexPath.row inSection:2]]
                              withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
        self.datePickerIndexPath = nil;
    }

    if (!sameCellClicked)
    {
        // hide the old date picker and display the new one
        NSInteger rowToReveal = (before ? indexPath.row - 1 : indexPath.row);
        NSIndexPath *indexPathToReveal = [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:rowToReveal inSection:2];

        [self toggleDatePickerForSelectedIndexPath:indexPathToReveal];
        self.datePickerIndexPath = [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:indexPathToReveal.row + 1 inSection:2];
    }

    // always deselect the row containing the start or end date
    [self.tableView deselectRowAtIndexPath:indexPath animated:YES];

    [self.tableView endUpdates];

    // inform our date picker of the current date to match the current cell
    [self updateDatePicker];
}

/*! Reveals the UIDatePicker as an external slide-in view, iOS 6.1.x and earlier, called by "didSelectRowAtIndexPath".

 @param indexPath The indexPath used to display the UIDatePicker.
 */
- (void)displayExternalDatePickerForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    // first update the date picker's date value according to our model
    NSDictionary *itemData = self.dataArray[indexPath.row];
    [self.pickerView setDate:[itemData valueForKey:kDateKey] animated:YES];

    // the date picker might already be showing, so don't add it to our view
    if (self.pickerView.superview == nil)
    {
        CGRect startFrame = self.pickerView.frame;
        CGRect endFrame = self.pickerView.frame;

        // the start position is below the bottom of the visible frame
        startFrame.origin.y = self.view.frame.size.height;

        // the end position is slid up by the height of the view
        endFrame.origin.y = startFrame.origin.y - endFrame.size.height;

        self.pickerView.frame = startFrame;

        [self.view addSubview:self.pickerView];

        // animate the date picker into view
        [UIView animateWithDuration:kPickerAnimationDuration animations: ^{ self.pickerView.frame = endFrame; }
                         completion:^(BOOL finished) {
                             // add the "Done" button to the nav bar
                             self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = self.doneButton;
                         }];
    }
}


#pragma mark - UITableViewDelegate

- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    if (indexPath.section == 0) {
        if (indexPath.row == 0) {
            UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
            cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryCheckmark;
            UITableViewCell *cell2 = [[self tableView] cellForRowAtIndexPath:[NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:1 inSection:0]];
            cell2.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryNone;
             [self.tableView deselectRowAtIndexPath:indexPath animated:YES];


        }else {
            UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
            cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryCheckmark;
            UITableViewCell *cell2 = [[self tableView] cellForRowAtIndexPath:[NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:0 inSection:0]];
            cell2.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryNone;
             [self.tableView deselectRowAtIndexPath:indexPath animated:YES];
        }
            }else {
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
    if (cell.reuseIdentifier == kDateCellID)
    {
        if (EMBEDDED_DATE_PICKER)
            [self displayInlineDatePickerForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
        else
            [self displayExternalDatePickerForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
    }
    else
    {
        [tableView deselectRowAtIndexPath:indexPath animated:YES];
    }
    }
}


#pragma mark - Actions

/*! User chose to change the date by changing the values inside the UIDatePicker.

 @param sender The sender for this action: UIDatePicker.
 */
- (IBAction)dateAction:(id)sender
{
    NSIndexPath *targetedCellIndexPath = nil;

    if ([self hasInlineDatePicker])
    {
        // inline date picker: update the cell's date "above" the date picker cell
        //
        targetedCellIndexPath = [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:self.datePickerIndexPath.row - 1 inSection:2];
    }
    else
    {
        // external date picker: update the current "selected" cell's date
        targetedCellIndexPath = [self.tableView indexPathForSelectedRow];
    }

    UITableViewCell *cell = [self.tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:targetedCellIndexPath];
    UIDatePicker *targetedDatePicker = sender;

    // update our data model
    NSMutableDictionary *itemData = self.dataArray[targetedCellIndexPath.row];
    [itemData setValue:targetedDatePicker.date forKey:kDateKey];

    // update the cell's date string
    cell.detailTextLabel.text = [self.dateFormatter stringFromDate:targetedDatePicker.date];
}


/*! User chose to finish using the UIDatePicker by pressing the "Done" button, (used only for non-inline date picker), iOS 6.1.x or earlier

 @param sender The sender for this action: The "Done" UIBarButtonItem
 */
- (IBAction)doneAction:(id)sender
{
    CGRect pickerFrame = self.pickerView.frame;
    pickerFrame.origin.y = self.view.frame.size.height;

    // animate the date picker out of view
    [UIView animateWithDuration:kPickerAnimationDuration animations: ^{ self.pickerView.frame = pickerFrame; }
                     completion:^(BOOL finished) {
                         [self.pickerView removeFromSuperview];
                     }];

    // remove the "Done" button in the navigation bar
    self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = nil;

    // deselect the current table cell
    NSIndexPath *indexPath = [self.tableView indexPathForSelectedRow];
    [self.tableView deselectRowAtIndexPath:indexPath animated:YES];
}

@end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I modified this sample code for my own app.  One thing I did, I modified the MutableDictionary in ViewDidLoad to change the "other cell" text to @"".  This made it basically blank, then I made the "Other Cells" background clear in the storyboard.  That may or may not work for you.  Apple really abstracts this code out a lot.  You can move the date info in the dictionary up to position 0 and the title down to position 2. Then change the values of the last 3 keys to @"".

This is the approach I took to modify this sample code.  If you start out like this, you might be able to get where you are wanting to go.

Here's is a screenshot from my app:

[image]

I don't know if it will let me post the image, I'm new to posting here.  But below is the code that I ended up using to make a tableview from the same sample code you are using. I left out a couple of imports and probably should have left out a lot more code that is not pertinent, but I just posted the whole tableViewController.  I figured a lot of this out by looking at an older version of the DateCell sample code.  It is FAR simpler.  But anyway, hope this helps.

```
#define kPickerAnimationDuration    0.40   // duration for the animation to slide the date picker into view
#define kDatePickerTag              99     // view tag identifiying the date picker view

#define kTitleKey       @"title"   // key for obtaining the data source item's title
#define kDateKey        @"date"    // key for obtaining the data source item's date value

// keep track of which rows have date cells
#define kDateStartRow   2
#define kDateEndRow     3

static NSString *kDateCellID = @"dateCell";     // the cells with the start or end date
static NSString *kDatePickerID = @"datePicker"; // the cell containing the date picker
static NSString *kOtherCell = @"otherCell";     // the remaining cells at the end

#pragma mark -

@interface EditShiftDetailViewController ()

@property (nonatomic, strong) NSArray *dataArray;
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter;

// keep track which indexPath points to the cell with UIDatePicker
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSIndexPath *datePickerIndexPath;

@property (assign) NSInteger pickerCellRowHeight;

@property (nonatomic, strong) IBOutlet UIDatePicker *pickerView;

// this button appears only when the date picker is shown (iOS 6.1.x or earlier)
@property (nonatomic, strong) IBOutlet UIBarButtonItem *doneButton;

@end

#pragma mark -

@implementation EditShiftDetailViewController

/*! Primary view has been loaded for this view controller
 */
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    UITapGestureRecognizer *gestureRecognizer = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(hideKeyboard)];
    gestureRecognizer.cancelsTouchesInView = NO;
    [self.tableView addGestureRecognizer:gestureRecognizer];

    // setup our data source
    NSMutableDictionary *itemOne = [@{ kTitleKey : @"Tap a cell to change its value:" } mutableCopy];
    NSMutableDictionary *itemTwo = [@{ kTitleKey : @"Shift Name:" } mutableCopy];
    NSMutableDictionary *itemThree = [@{ kTitleKey : @"Start Time",
                                         kDateKey : self.currentShift.startTime } mutableCopy];
    NSMutableDictionary *itemFour = [@{ kTitleKey : @"End Time",
                                        kDateKey : self.currentShift.endTime } mutableCopy];
   NSMutableDictionary *itemFive = [@{ kTitleKey : @"" } mutableCopy] ;
    self.dataArray = @[itemOne, itemTwo, itemThree, itemFour, itemFive];


    self.dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
    [self.dateFormatter setDateStyle:NSDateFormatterNoStyle];    // Don't show date
    [self.dateFormatter setTimeStyle:NSDateFormatterShortStyle]; // show short-style time format

    // obtain the picker view cell's height, works because the cell was pre-defined in our storyboard
    UITableViewCell *pickerViewCellToCheck = [self.tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:kDatePickerID];
    self.pickerCellRowHeight = pickerViewCellToCheck.frame.size.height;

    //self.shiftNameField.text = self.currentShift.shiftName;

    self.title = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@, %@", self.currentDay.name, self.currentShift.shiftName];

    // if the local changes while in the background, we need to be notified so we can update the date
    // format in the table view cells
    //
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
                                             selector:@selector(localeChanged:)
                                                 name:NSCurrentLocaleDidChangeNotification
                                               object:nil];
}

- (void)viewWillDisappear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [super viewWillDisappear:animated];
    self.currentShift.startTime = [self.dataArray[2] valueForKey:kDateKey];
    self.currentShift.endTime = [self.dataArray[3] valueForKey:kDateKey];
    [[MyManager sharedManager] saveChanges];
}

- (void) hideKeyboard
{
    [self.view endEditing:YES];
}

- (void)dealloc
{
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] removeObserver:self
                                                    name:NSCurrentLocaleDidChangeNotification
                                                  object:nil];
}


#pragma mark - Locale

/*! Responds to region format or locale changes.
 */
- (void)localeChanged:(NSNotification *)notif
{
    // the user changed the locale (region format) in Settings, so we are notified here to
    // update the date format in the table view cells
    //
    [self.tableView reloadData];
}


#pragma mark - Utilities

/*! Returns the major version of iOS, (i.e. for iOS 6.1.3 it returns 6)
 */
NSUInteger DeviceSystemMajorVersion()
{
    static NSUInteger _deviceSystemMajorVersion = -1;
    static dispatch_once_t onceToken;
    dispatch_once(&onceToken, ^{

        _deviceSystemMajorVersion = [[[[[UIDevice currentDevice] systemVersion] componentsSeparatedByString:@"."] objectAtIndex:0] intValue];
    });

    return _deviceSystemMajorVersion;
}

#define EMBEDDED_DATE_PICKER (DeviceSystemMajorVersion() >= 7)

/*! Determines if the given indexPath has a cell below it with a UIDatePicker.

 @param indexPath The indexPath to check if its cell has a UIDatePicker below it.
 */
- (BOOL)hasPickerForIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    BOOL hasDatePicker = NO;

    NSInteger targetedRow = indexPath.row;
    targetedRow++;

    UITableViewCell *checkDatePickerCell =
    [self.tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:[NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:targetedRow inSection:0]];
    UIDatePicker *checkDatePicker = (UIDatePicker *)[checkDatePickerCell viewWithTag:kDatePickerTag];

    hasDatePicker = (checkDatePicker != nil);
    return hasDatePicker;
}

/*! Updates the UIDatePicker's value to match with the date of the cell above it.
 */
- (void)updateDatePicker
{
    if (self.datePickerIndexPath != nil)
    {
        UITableViewCell *associatedDatePickerCell = [self.tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:self.datePickerIndexPath];

        UIDatePicker *targetedDatePicker = (UIDatePicker *)[associatedDatePickerCell viewWithTag:kDatePickerTag];
        if (targetedDatePicker != nil)
        {
            // we found a UIDatePicker in this cell, so update it's date value
            //
            NSDictionary *itemData = self.dataArray[self.datePickerIndexPath.row - 1];
            [targetedDatePicker setDate:[itemData valueForKey:kDateKey] animated:NO];

        }
    }
}

/*! Determines if the UITableViewController has a UIDatePicker in any of its cells.
 */
- (BOOL)hasInlineDatePicker
{
    return (self.datePickerIndexPath != nil);
}

/*! Determines if the given indexPath points to a cell that contains the UIDatePicker.

 @param indexPath The indexPath to check if it represents a cell with the UIDatePicker.
 */
- (BOOL)indexPathHasPicker:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    return ([self hasInlineDatePicker] && self.datePickerIndexPath.row == indexPath.row);
}

/*! Determines if the given indexPath points to a cell that contains the start/end dates.

 @param indexPath The indexPath to check if it represents start/end date cell.
 */

- (BOOL)indexPathHasShiftName:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    return (indexPath.row == 1);
}

- (BOOL)indexPathHasDate:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    BOOL hasDate = NO;

    if ((indexPath.row == kDateStartRow) ||
        (indexPath.row == kDateEndRow || ([self hasInlineDatePicker] && (indexPath.row == kDateEndRow + 1))))
    {
        hasDate = YES;
    }

    return hasDate;
}

- (BOOL)textFieldShouldReturn:(UITextField *)textField
{
    [textField resignFirstResponder];
    self.currentShift.shiftName = textField.text;
    self.title = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@, %@", self.currentDay.name, self.currentShift.shiftName];
    [self.tableView reloadData];

    return YES;
}

#pragma mark - UITableViewDataSource

- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    return ([self indexPathHasPicker:indexPath] ? self.pickerCellRowHeight : self.tableView.rowHeight);
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    if ([self hasInlineDatePicker])
    {
        // we have a date picker, so allow for it in the number of rows in this section
        NSInteger numRows = self.dataArray.count;
        return ++numRows;
    }

    return self.dataArray.count;
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    UITableViewCell *cell = nil;



    NSString *cellID = kOtherCell;


    if ([self indexPathHasPicker:indexPath])
    {
        // the indexPath is the one containing the inline date picker
        cellID = kDatePickerID;     // the current/opened date picker cell
    }
    else if ([self indexPathHasDate:indexPath])
    {
        // the indexPath is one that contains the date information
        cellID = kDateCellID;       // the start/end date cells
    }
    else if ([self indexPathHasShiftName:indexPath])
    {
        cellID = @"shiftNameCell";
    }



    cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:cellID];


    if (indexPath.row == 0)
    {
        // we decide here that first cell in the table is not selectable (it's just an indicator)
        cell.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone;
    }



    // if we have a date picker open whose cell is above the cell we want to update,
    // then we have one more cell than the model allows
    //
    NSInteger modelRow = indexPath.row;
    if (self.datePickerIndexPath != nil && self.datePickerIndexPath.row < indexPath.row)
    {
        modelRow--;
    }

    NSDictionary *itemData = self.dataArray[modelRow];

    // proceed to configure our cell
    if ([cellID isEqualToString:kDateCellID])
    {
        // we have either start or end date cells, populate their date field
        //
        cell.textLabel.text = [itemData valueForKey:kTitleKey];
        cell.detailTextLabel.text = [self.dateFormatter stringFromDate:[itemData valueForKey:kDateKey]];
    }
    else if ([cellID isEqualToString:@"shiftNameCell"])
    {
        UITextField *txtField = (UITextField *)[cell viewWithTag:8];
        txtField.delegate = self;
        txtField.enablesReturnKeyAutomatically = YES;
        txtField.returnKeyType = UIReturnKeyDone;
        txtField.text = self.currentShift.shiftName;
    }
    else if ([cellID isEqualToString:kOtherCell])
    {
        // this cell is a non-date cell, just assign it's text label
        //
        /*if (indexPath.row == 4) {
            NSTimeInterval timeInterval = [self.currentShift.endTime timeIntervalSinceDate:self.currentShift.startTime];

            NSString *cellText = [self stringFromTimeInterval:timeInterval];

            cell.textLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Shift Length %@ hours", cellText];
        } else { */
        cell.textLabel.text = [itemData valueForKey:kTitleKey];
       // }
    }

    return cell;
}

- (NSString *)stringFromTimeInterval:(NSTimeInterval)interval {
    NSInteger ti = (NSInteger)interval;
    NSInteger minutes = (ti / 60) % 60;
    NSInteger hour = (ti / 3600);
    return [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%i:%02i", hour, minutes];
}

/*! Adds or removes a UIDatePicker cell below the given indexPath.

 @param indexPath The indexPath to reveal the UIDatePicker.
 */
- (void)toggleDatePickerForSelectedIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    [self.tableView beginUpdates];

    NSArray *indexPaths = @[[NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:indexPath.row + 1 inSection:0]];

    // check if 'indexPath' has an attached date picker below it
    if ([self hasPickerForIndexPath:indexPath])
    {
        // found a picker below it, so remove it
        [self.tableView deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:indexPaths
                              withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
    }
    else
    {
        // didn't find a picker below it, so we should insert it
        [self.tableView insertRowsAtIndexPaths:indexPaths
                              withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
    }

    [self.tableView endUpdates];
}

/*! Reveals the date picker inline for the given indexPath, called by "didSelectRowAtIndexPath".

 @param indexPath The indexPath to reveal the UIDatePicker.
 */
- (void)displayInlineDatePickerForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    // display the date picker inline with the table content
    [self.tableView beginUpdates];

    BOOL before = NO;   // indicates if the date picker is below "indexPath", help us determine which row to reveal
    if ([self hasInlineDatePicker])
    {
        before = self.datePickerIndexPath.row < indexPath.row;
    }

    BOOL sameCellClicked = (self.datePickerIndexPath.row - 1 == indexPath.row);

    // remove any date picker cell if it exists
    if ([self hasInlineDatePicker])
    {
        [self.tableView deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:@[[NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:self.datePickerIndexPath.row inSection:0]]
                              withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
        self.datePickerIndexPath = nil;
    }

    if (!sameCellClicked)
    {
        // hide the old date picker and display the new one
        NSInteger rowToReveal = (before ? indexPath.row - 1 : indexPath.row);
        NSIndexPath *indexPathToReveal = [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:rowToReveal inSection:0];

        [self toggleDatePickerForSelectedIndexPath:indexPathToReveal];
        self.datePickerIndexPath = [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:indexPathToReveal.row + 1 inSection:0];
    }

    // always deselect the row containing the start or end date
    [self.tableView deselectRowAtIndexPath:indexPath animated:YES];

    [self.tableView endUpdates];

    // inform our date picker of the current date to match the current cell
    [self updateDatePicker];

}

/*! Reveals the UIDatePicker as an external slide-in view, iOS 6.1.x and earlier, called by "didSelectRowAtIndexPath".

 @param indexPath The indexPath used to display the UIDatePicker.
 */
- (void)displayExternalDatePickerForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    // first update the date picker's date value according to our model
    NSDictionary *itemData = self.dataArray[indexPath.row];
    [self.pickerView setDatePickerMode:UIDatePickerModeTime];
    [self.pickerView setMinuteInterval:5];
    [self.pickerView setDate:[itemData valueForKey:kDateKey] animated:YES];

    // the date picker might already be showing, so don't add it to our view
    if (self.pickerView.superview == nil)
    {
        CGRect startFrame = self.pickerView.frame;
        CGRect endFrame = self.pickerView.frame;

        // the start position is below the bottom of the visible frame
        startFrame.origin.y = self.view.frame.size.height;

        // the end position is slid up by the height of the view
        endFrame.origin.y = startFrame.origin.y - endFrame.size.height;

        self.pickerView.frame = startFrame;

        [self.view addSubview:self.pickerView];

        // animate the date picker into view
        [UIView animateWithDuration:kPickerAnimationDuration animations: ^{ self.pickerView.frame = endFrame; }
                         completion:^(BOOL finished) {
                             // add the "Done" button to the nav bar
                             self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = self.doneButton;
                         }];
    }
}


#pragma mark - UITableViewDelegate

- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
    if (cell.reuseIdentifier == kDateCellID)
    {
        if (EMBEDDED_DATE_PICKER)
            [self displayInlineDatePickerForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
        else
            [self displayExternalDatePickerForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
    }
    else
    {
        [tableView deselectRowAtIndexPath:indexPath animated:YES];

    }
}


#pragma mark - Actions

/*! User chose to change the date by changing the values inside the UIDatePicker.

 @param sender The sender for this action: UIDatePicker.
 */
- (IBAction)dateAction:(id)sender
{
    NSIndexPath *targetedCellIndexPath = nil;

    if ([self hasInlineDatePicker])
    {
        // inline date picker: update the cell's date "above" the date picker cell
        //
        targetedCellIndexPath = [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:self.datePickerIndexPath.row - 1 inSection:0];
    }
    else
    {
        // external date picker: update the current "selected" cell's date
        targetedCellIndexPath = [self.tableView indexPathForSelectedRow];
    }

    UITableViewCell *cell = [self.tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:targetedCellIndexPath];
    UIDatePicker *targetedDatePicker = sender;

    // update our data model
    NSMutableDictionary *itemData = self.dataArray[targetedCellIndexPath.row];
    [itemData setValue:targetedDatePicker.date forKey:kDateKey];

    // update the cell's date string
    cell.detailTextLabel.text = [self.dateFormatter stringFromDate:targetedDatePicker.date];
    [[MyManager sharedManager] saveChanges];
    [self.tableView reloadData];
}


/*! User chose to finish using the UIDatePicker by pressing the "Done" button, (used only for non-inline date picker), iOS 6.1.x or earlier

 @param sender The sender for this action: The "Done" UIBarButtonItem
 */
- (IBAction)doneAction:(id)sender
{
    CGRect pickerFrame = self.pickerView.frame;
    pickerFrame.origin.y = self.view.frame.size.height;

    // animate the date picker out of view
    [UIView animateWithDuration:kPickerAnimationDuration animations: ^{ self.pickerView.frame = pickerFrame; }
                     completion:^(BOOL finished) {
                         [self.pickerView removeFromSuperview];
                     }];

    // remove the "Done" button in the navigation bar
    self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = nil;

    // deselect the current table cell
    NSIndexPath *indexPath = [self.tableView indexPathForSelectedRow];
    [self.tableView deselectRowAtIndexPath:indexPath animated:YES];
}

@end
```